# How to change UIActivityController view to forceRightToLeft always

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivitycontroller

UIActivityController view is not supporting rtl. I have set UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft in AppDelegate. If device language is English ActivityController is still opening in leftToRight instead of RightToLeft.
It is working fine with device language is Arabic.
Even I have tried to make activity controller view to rightToleft but no luck.
[image]

Should be rightToLeft.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `languages` in localisation section under info section in Xcode.

for more details checkout this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/preparing-your-interface-for-localization)

[image]

output:
[image]

Comment: Already Added, but no luck. It is working fine if device language is arabic. i have also added UiView.appearence().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft  in appDelegate

Comment: Once I choose mail option option from share Activity it is subject text getting overlap

Comment: another way is transform UI but in this approach Text also rotate with Alert UI mirroring